# jpa one-to-many with target inheritance joined do not save key on subtable

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have this model on JPA 2 with hibernate 4.3 as provider.

Person

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
  private List<Animal> animals;
```

Animal

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMAL")
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ANIMAL_TYPE")
@IdClass(AnimalPK.class)
public class Animal implements Serializable
{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private long id;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID_ANIMAL")
  private int idAnimal;
```

Cat

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAT")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "CAT")
public class Cat extends Animal
{
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
```

On ER model:

```
Person:
ID

Animal:
ID
ID_ANIMAL
ANIMAL_TYPE

Cat:
ID
ID_ANIMAL
ANIMAL_TYPE
NAME
```

When I load a person and add an animal and update the person it happens something strange, the operation is successfull but what I got is that on the one-to-many hibernate saves only the ID of the person on the super table (Animal) and not on the sub-table (Cat).

Person:
    ID --> 1

```
Animal:
ID --> 1
ID_ANIMAL --> 1
ANIMAL_TYPE --> Cat

Cat:
ID --> 0
ID_ANIMAL --> 1
ANIMAL_TYPE --> Cat
NAME --> name
```

Comment: Saving person_id in the Cat table is surely redundant as you can link Cat to Person via Animal.

Comment: You are also using a JOINED strategy so you do not need the Discrimator columns.

Comment: You're right for the redundancy, but the example is only for the sake of the discussion: I have to work with e legacy ER model similar to that exposed.

Comment: Also in JOINED strategy you can use the discriminator COLUMN, and this save me for write the ANIMAL_TYPE on the Animal table. (for the legacy explanation above).

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings should look like the below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PERSON implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="person")
    private List<Animal> animals;
}
```

Animal

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMAL")
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
public class Animal implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_ANIMAL")
    private int idAnimal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON")
    private Person person;
}
```

Cat

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAT")
public class Cat extends Animal
{
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I tried but this solution do not solve the problem exposed: same behaviour as before: the ID is only saved on the super table (Animal and not Cat).

Comment: As advised previously you do not have a problem. This is the **EXPECTED** behaviour. Saving the owner's id in CAT is **REDUNDANT** as you can get the owner via the relationship to  ANIMAL.